# How to send messages on twisted python package without encoding and decoding?

Tags: python, twisted

[I have three clients and I want to send messages using twisted package on python3 and I don't want to be encoded and decode, I want to send the messages as numbers without enc-dec to string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQEi8.png)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't post a link to an external hosting site that has an image of the text of your source.  Just put the text of the source in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to send the messages as numbers without enc-dec to string.

Do you understand why encoding and decoding is necessary? Data is passed through networks as bytes. Applications are responsible for translating bytes to and from higher level data structures. To be very blunt, you cannot send/receive messages without encoding and decoding to bytes.